# How to show progress on a progress bar at activity start

Tags: java, android, android-activity, loading, activity-lifecycle

I want to launch an activity, and show the progress of the loading of the activity as methods are completed. The methods will, for example, be downloading data. The problem is, the loading bar never actually shows as empty at the beginning, it simply loads once all methods are complete and shows 100% full.

I have tested a few implementations, but with no luck. The current state I am in is that I set the loading bar to max in *onCreate*, then carry out processing in *onWindowFocusChanged*. The issue is, that the loading bar is never drawn after *onCreate*. I have tested placing methods into *onResume* also, but again the progress bar only appears AFTER onCreate, *onResume* and *onWindowFocusChanged* have all completed. This has thrown my understanding of the activity lifecycle off a bit as I thought all visual elements should be drawn after *onCreate*?

My current code is as follows (note that no difference is noticed if the code in onWindowFocusChanged is placed in onResume). This code is all prototyping code in an attempt to get this to work.

```
public class IntermediateLoadingScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressBar loadingBar = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intermediate_loading_screen);
        loadingBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.intermediateLoadingBar);
        loadingBar.setMax(100);
        Log.d("IntermediateLoadScreen","onCreate Complete");    
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume () {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("IntermediateLoadScreen","onResume");
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        Log.d("IntermediateLoadScreen","onWindowFocusChanged");
        if(hasFocus){
            AsyncCollectDeviceData asyncCollectDeviceData = new AsyncCollectDeviceData(this.getApplicationContext());
            asyncCollectDeviceData.execute();
            loadingBar.setProgress(15);
            Log.d("IntermediateLoadScreen", "Loading");
            getUserContactsFromServer();
            getUserGroupsFromServer();
            loadingBar.setProgress(100);
            /*Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);*/
        }
    }

    public void getUserContactsFromServer(){
        Log.d("IntermediateLoadScreen", "getUserContactsFromServer");
        loadingBar.setProgress(35);
        ContactsResponse contactsResponse = new ServerRequest().submitContactsRequest();
        new UserRealmDAO().updateContacts(contactsResponse);
        loadingBar.setProgress(60);
    }

    public void getUserGroupsFromServer(){
        Log.d("IntermediateLoadScreen", "getUserGroupsFromServer");
        loadingBar.setProgress(80);
        GroupsResponse groupsResponse = new ServerRequest().submitGroupsRequest();
        new UserRealmDAO().updateGroups(groupsResponse);
        loadingBar.setProgress(95);
    }
}
```

I understand that I shouldn't really have a loading screen in an activity of it's own, and should probably have it as part of an activity that I can make visible when required. But the same activity flow should occur, so if I can get this example working it should transfer across.

To conclude, the loading bar does not show after onCreate, the previous activity simply hangs and a complete loading bar eventually pops up. How can I have the empty loading bar drawn at the beginning and fill it as i call 'loadingBar.setProgress'?

EDIT:
These are my logs I have added to the above activity, I have moved the code shown in *onWindowFocusChanged* into *onResume*:

```
01-20 13:10:15.430 /IntermediateLoadScreen: onCreate Complete
01-20 13:10:15.430 /IntermediateLoadScreen: onResume
01-20 13:10:20.425 /IntermediateLoadScreen: Bar set at progress 15
01-20 13:10:26.242 /IntermediateLoadScreen: Bar set at progress 80
01-20 13:10:31.457 /IntermediateLoadScreen: Bar set at progress 100
```

The first (splashscreen) activity stays displayed until all these logs have printed out. I have placed a Thread.sleep before every progress bar set call, so you can see that there is a at least 5 seconds between each log. Even after doing this, my activity does not display until ALL method calls in the entire class are complete.

Comment: Just Curious. What are you trying to achieve ? Are you trying to do some heavy duty task and update the progress bar once it is done ? Any UI update on the UI thread. And from your code it looks like you are doing all the heavy duty task on the UI thread which might interfere with the UI update.

Comment: Try the simple work pattern shown in the Progress bar dev page - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html   Offload all work to a secondary thread.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll read over that link!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` will be called right after activity is created. So your progress bar will have 15% at beginning.
Also all your methods may run really fast, so they will be done before user can actually see some progress

Comment: But it doesn't, I don't even see the loading bar until it is complete. The previous activity hangs, all this activity's logs print out, and then it displays as complete. I see no change in progress. I have also tested sleeps in the methods to slow it down, same result as described.

Comment: @Calco log every progress change. You will see that the difference in time between logs must be really small. So your activity have time to start,render and display when tasks are already finished. If you want to start tasks only after activity really displayed on screen, use some `post()` methods.

Comment: I have tested with sleeps and moving code into onResume. Please refer to the edit in the post. The empty loading bar is simply never shown until all method calls in the activity finish.

Comment: What if you woudn't set progress at all after 15%? Will it be 15?

Comment: Also, sleeps are stoping current thread, which in your case is `UI THREAD`. You won't see any update if you stop UI thread )

Comment: Ah yes ofcourse. If I don't set progress beyond 15, I simply see it as 15.

Comment: So, in your case all code is done on UI thread (as far as I can see), so you wouldn't see any changes until all your code is done working

Comment: So it is correct that I am not seeing an empty loading bar after onCreate? Should the activity not display the layout before moving on the onStart/onResume?

Comment: Nope, it shouldn't. Activity is displayed only after `onResume()`

Comment: So how would I make a method call beyond onResume?

Comment: You can get some view from your activity (progress bar for example) and do progressBar.post(...); this way code in progress bar will run only after activity is displayed. Or move all your code into AcyncTask and run it from onCreate (this is definitely better way, because running long tasks on UI thread is really bad practice)

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that my method does some processing and then calls another async task. So I need to restructure the code. Or I think I can call the method as an async task as long as I only create the second async task in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion here. Generally if any data is to be loaded/background process to take place, there is a new feature in Android Lollipop called SplASHsCREEN. Try using THIS Splash screen- a basic app screen where it will be shown till you load all your data and after it loads, you can show the next screen.

This gives user a good feel just after launching the app instead of displaying progress bar.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a look into this. When you say screen, are you referring to a separate activity, or just a layout element that hides itself?

Comment: Hi @Calco, You can look into SPlash screen tutorial here : [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/)                                                                                                                      Splash screen is just an activity that has its own layout and you can display your activity logo or anything you want in that.                                                             Best example is Google Maps. Try looking at the splash screen when you opengoogle maps.